# How do you re-use Stripe customers?

Tags: stripe-payments

I've been looking through the docs, other tuts, but nothing is straight forward on this.

The docs shows:

```
saveStripeCustomerId($user, $customer->id);
```

There's not one line of code, or comment to explain where, or what code is in this function.

another person asked on here how do you store tokens. The answer was don't store tokens save customer IDs, or something like save customers. They neglected to say how or where to save them..

Can I ask the questions once and for all?

How do you re-use Stripe customers?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to get involved with subscriptions at all to create a customer. A Customer is required to create a subscription, but not the other way around.

This line of code below is an example of a function you would create and run to save the customerId to your database, it is not a stripe function. It would be up to you to populate that function and handle the database transaction.

```
// Save the customer ID in your database so you can use it later
saveStripeCustomerId($user, $customer->id);
```

This line of code more specifically is the creation of a customer. When executed it will return a customer object which you can use, and add/remove cards to/from, and charge those cards.

```
// Create a Customer
$customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
  "card" => $token,
  "description" => "payinguser@example.com")
);
```

By saving the customerId to your database you can retrieve and charge that customer at any time without storing a credit card or personal information.

Comment: I know but what's stupid is that it showed that save customer function without telling me it was user defined. I searched forever to find out what I was supposed to save to re-charge later... the customer ID... but found that information in subscription section of docs.. I just think Stripe should have been more straight forward with that information. I didn't know if that save function was part of the framework, or what, lol.

Comment: I edited my post to show what I saw on the documents page where I found that line of code you were talking about. In the comment right above it, stripe states what the purpose of that function is. IMO Stripe has some of the best documentation I have seen for an api.

Comment: I know, I seen the comment on Stipe's website. The problem is, them not telling me it was user defined left me scratching my head... saying that a function saves info to a database is only a hint, and not a big enough one. What database? Mine as in my site, or mine as in in Stripe account somewhere? Then they put the information you need on saving customers in subscriptions, somewhere not everyone will need because they're not using subscriptions...sorry, but that's not good organization, or informativeness... aside from that, yes, well written. :P

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, but assume no responsibility for my lack of understanding, lol.

The docs say:

Once you've created a customer, you should store its id in your own database so you can refer to it later when communicating with stripe.

but guess where? Under subscription, something I assumed I would never need because I'm not doing anything with subscriptions. I would think this important detail would have been mentioned with customers...

Comment: Wiat, can you explain this a little more? In order to use an existing customer, I need to setup a subscription?